# CircleCi YAML config gives unexpected string error

Tags: yaml, circleci

Despite using copy and paste I keep getting the following error when I try to validate my YAML using

```
circleci config validate
```

I get this error

```
Error: Unable to parse YAML
while parsing a block mapping
 in 'string', line 30, column 5:
        <<: *defaults
        ^
expected <block end>, but found '<block mapping start>'
 in 'string', line 31, column 7:
          steps:
          ^
```

The yaml causing the error is the deploy-job-canada:

```
  # Deploy the project to google
  deploy-job:
    <<: *defaults
    steps:
      - attach_workspace:
          at: ~/repo
      - run:
          name: Firebase set project-id
          command: ./node_modules/.bin/firebase use production --token=$FIREBASE_DEPLOY_TOKEN
      - run:
          name: Deploy Master to Firebase
          command: ./node_modules/.bin/firebase deploy --token=$FIREBASE_DEPLOY_TOKEN

  deploy-job-canada:
    <<: *defaults
      steps:
        - attach_workspace:
            at: ~/repo
        - run:
            name: Firebase set project-id
            command: ./node_modules/.bin/firebase use canada --token=$FIREBASE_DEPLOY_TOKEN_CANADA
        - run:
            name: Deploy Master to Firebase
            command: ./node_modules/.bin/firebase deploy --token=$FIREBASE_DEPLOY_TOKEN_CANADA
```

For reference, if I just include deploy-job it works fine, I replicated this job exactly so am very confused how I can have ended up with that error

Comment: look at the indentation of `steps:` in the first case and the second case. For the first one you got it right. For the second one, you got 2 spaces too much.

Comment: INDENTION WAS THE KEY!!!  Thank you, sir!